# Why can't a 1 go in this field

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I've moved onto "expert" sudoku's in my app (Sudoku.com on IOS) and whilst I am getting by solving some, others I'm having a hard time with.

With this one, I used a hint so the AI could note all the fields up for me but it hasn't put a note for 1 in this box. Why? I can't see anything which would rule it out for "certain". I know there are 2 possible 1's on the same line in block 9 but it also has the possibility of being on the line above so isn't certain in my mind.

Can someone explain why the AI can be sure no 1 should be in this box?

[image]

Comment: I guess you can more or less just solve the sudoku, and in the end you'll get a contradiction for the other ordering of the 1+6 pair in R8C45. (To solve the sudoku, notice that column 5 has a 2+4 pair at the top, so box 2 will have a *very* useful 156 triple in column 6.)

Comment: @Bass I see a 4+5 and 2+4 in the top at column 5. Am I missing a 2+4 pair somewhere?

Comment: @webnoob Ignoring the hints, just notice that column 6 already contains both 2 and 4, so the remaining two entries in box 2 must be 2 and 4.

Comment: Ah ofc, can't see the wood for the tree's now. Thanks @RobPratt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there were a one in that cell, there would be no place left for the six to go in its column.

Comment: While this answers the question asked, it isn't very helpful. Why is that the only location for 6 in that column? How has 6 been ruled out from R1C5 and R2C5?

Comment: Yes, I agree. According to the notes, 6 can be in 2 places in that block so how have you deduced this?

Comment: Ok, I see now that the 6 only has one place in that column but I guess I'm still struggling to see why a 6 couldn't go in some of the other cells i.e R4C5 and R1C5, R2C5

Comment: sudokuspoiler.com confirms that the puzzle (just the large black numbers) does have a unique solution, but doesn't explain its reasoning either. Wonder if anyone's built a site that explains its deductions step by step?

Comment: My favourite online step-by-step solver (sudokuwiki.org) finds a naked triple in R1C6/R2C6/R3C6, after which you have naked single 5s in R7 and in C5. It dies not somehow eliminate all the canditates that are missing in the OP's picture.

Comment: .. but that solver also can't finish the puzzle with its built-in logic techniques. That shows it is a very difficult sudoku for which you will likely need to just have to use trial and error (i.e. guess and backtrack if you fail).

Comment: Ah, I kind of assumed it was just my lack of knowledge with certain patterns etc. Didn't expect to need to brute force / bifurcate it a little :)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis you must have made a typo. Apart from a single inference chain (solved by "simple colouring" by the bot) which restricts the 2s in column 8, the solver doesn't need anything except the basic deductions to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @Bass You're right, I must have accidentally missed out one of the clues when I entered it.

Comment: @Bass I completed it last night and yes, you're right. Standard deductions were required. There was a little bit of forward thinking required i.e "If this numer went there" - what would it mean but it was solvable without anything else.